# Add a static text to a separate panel in separate class (wxpython)

Tags: wxpython

I have a notebook, that has it's own class, in that notebook I have a checkbutton, I'm trying to  bind that check button show the static text on a separate panel that's in a separate class.

Ex.

```
class ButtonPage(wx.Notebook)
    def __init__(etc.....):
        but_img = wx.Bitmap('./button.png',wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    self.but_img = wx.StaticBitmap(self,bitmap=but_img,pos=((10,170)),style=wx.NO_BORDER)

class PanelPage(wx.Frame)
    def __init__(etc....)
    self.mainPanel = wx.Panel(self,etc....)
```

So how do I bind this button in the 'Button Page' to show a statictext on the PanelPage if they are in 2 separate classes. I'm use to making the parent of the button (self) but seeing as in this instance it makes no sense to do so....

Edit: Ok I actually figured it out. But for some reason wx.StaticText doesn't respond to EVT calls. Any ideas why this is? ways around it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want. StaticText is just a label. The user doesn't interact with labels, so there really aren't any events for this widget. You might be able to bind some mouse events for the section of the screen that the label is on, but I think that's it.

A good way to make two classes in wxPython talk to each other is to use pubsub. Here's a tutorial for you http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

EDIT: To change what page is shown in a Notebook, you'll want to use the Notebook's SetSelection() method or ChangeSelection method. Assuming both panels are in the same notebook, you'd just call the Notebook instance to change pages. That should work even without pubsub.

However, if you're talking about something outside the notebook, then the pubsub method is definitely the way to go.

Comment: He's not looking to interact with the label directly, just update/show it when a button is pressed on another panel

Answer (score 0):

For a bit of a quick a dirty solution, you could pass a reference to the StaticText through to your 'Button Page' via the init method for instance, then you could bind a method in the Button Page class to the EVT_BUTTON event and call `SetLabel` on the label from there.

A slightly nicer solution though is to do this at the parent level, by the sounds of things the ButtonPage and PanelPages are siblings on a notebook, so you could bind the button in the ButtonPage from the notebook class, and use the same method as above. It's slightly nicer having a parent doing this rather than passing through a reference of a sibling's object/method.

I just thought I'd mention this if its only a small project and you need to get something working quickly

Alternatively Mikes solution is a little bit more work to set up and get to grips with (but it's worth it). It's more readable, and using the solution above will 'couple' the code quite a lot and if things change in the future you'll have a bit of a mess to untangle.